# Why doesn't FileProvider work everywhere?

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am quite new in android programming and writing shop assistant with scan from camera. I use fileprovider to not loose quality of photos using standard camera app. But on some phones app crash on moment of taking picture when I press tick in camera app:

[In this moment i press tick and app crashes on Some phones (but on some works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nelQY.png)

Here is my code of provider:

Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

taking picture:

```
private void takePicture() {
        try{
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            try {
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
                File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
                File file = new File(pictureImagePath);
                Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {

            } finally {
                someActivityResultLauncher.launch(cameraIntent);
            }
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.camera_not_recog), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                /**
                 * Method to take user's photo
                 * @param result
                 */
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        try {
                            File imgFile = new File(pictureImagePath);
                            // Check if file exists
                            if (imgFile.exists()) {
                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            } else {
                                assert data != null;
                                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                                bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            assert data != null;
                            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                            bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                        } finally {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What's the crash?  Is it in your app or the other app?

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash, if that crash is in your app: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html